# Apache Ignite Cache Error:caused by java.lang.illegalstateexception : Cache has been closed or destroyed: cacheName

Tags: ignite

The exception sometimes comes on the start of application,more frequently  during the performance of the application .Moreover,the application starts slowly.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your client node disconnects for some reason. You can check this by subscribing to `EVT_CLIENT_NODE_DISCONNECTED` event on the client (see [1] for more info on how to do this).

If this happens frequently, then there are some serious issues. The first thing I would check is the memory. Make sure that you're not running out of it and that you do not experience long GC pauses.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/events