# Apache Ignite cache has been closed or destroyed

Tags: ignite

recently we've deployed the application with ignite cache enabled. We have three servers and the cache mode is replicated. All three servers are server nodes. After deploying the application, the exception "cache has been closed or destroyed" is thrown randomly.

I've checked the previous question from StackOverflow ([Apache Ignite Cache Error:caused by java.lang.illegalstateexception : Cache has been closed or destroyed: cacheName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384072/apache-ignite-cache-errorcaused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cache-has)) but it cannot solve my problem.

Is there anyone encountered the same exception before? If yes, how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

This exception means that either `IgniteCache.close()` was called on a particular instance of `IgniteCache` that you're using, of `IgniteCache.destroy`/`Ignite.destroyCache(..)` was called for this cache anywhere in the cluster. Check your code and make sure this is not happening.

Another scenario is client disconnection described in the thread link to which you provided.